# ImageFiled not working on update in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-media

I have a custom form to update record in Django. everything working fine except the image.

```
updated = Brand.objects.filter(brand_id = brand_id).update(brand_name = brand_name, brand_slug = brand_slug,
brand_logo_alt_text = brand_logo_alt_text, brand_title = brand_title, category_id = brand_category,
country_id = brand_country,brand_info = brand_info, brand_description = brand_desc, brand_logo = brand_logo)
```

Media setup was perfect and everything working correct on creating new records but when I update this image not shown in media directory but in database image URL properly stored.

What's exactly the problem is? and please provide a suitable solution for the same.

Comment: Of course - you are only updating the db indeed. Hint: use a ModelForm.

Comment: No, I am using custom forms is there any other solution?

Comment: What prevents a ModelForm from being customized exactly ??? Yes there are "other solutions" (which are documented), but this amounts to rewrite what's already there.